# Como guardar valor de uma função que retorna um ponteiro char num vetor de strings

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber como posso armazenar o retorno da função abaixo, que gera uma string aleatória, num vetor de strings com 100 dessas palavras geradas pela função, para depois fazer uma ordenação - crescente e decrescente - no vetor.

```
char* geraStringAleatoria(){

char *validchars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char *novastr;
register int i;
int str_len;

// novo tamanho
str_len = (rand() % MAX_STR_SIZE );

// checa tamanho
str_len += ( str_len < MIN_STR_SIZE ) ? MIN_STR_SIZE : 0;

// aloca memoria
novastr = ( char * ) malloc ( (str_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
if ( !novastr ){
    printf("[*] Erro ao alocar memoria.\n" );
    exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// gera string aleatória
for ( i = 0; i < str_len; i++ ) {
    novastr[i] = validchars[ rand() % strlen(validchars) ];
    novastr[i + 1] = 0x0;
}

   return novastr;
}
```

Na função main eu consigo atribuir o retorno da função a uma string:

```
int main() {
    char *str;
    str = geraStringAleatoria();

   return 0;
}
```

Mas não sei como fazer para armazenar cada palavra gerada num vetor de strings, como se cada posição do vetor fosse uma palavra.

Comment: o que você tentou? quais problemas está enfrentando?

Comment: Tentei armazenar o retorno da função em uma matriz de string: char palavras[ i ][ j ] = geraStringAleatoria(); - sendo i o numero de caracteres e j o numero de palavras. Mas acho que isso não faz muito sentido, não sei como fazer sou iniciante, acredito que estou atribuindo tipos diferentes, e não sei como faria para armazenar o retorno da função num vetor com as palavras geradas

Comment: Outra coisa: identação não é brinquedo. Use, e use de forma a ficar mais fácil de ler seu programa.
Se tiver preguiça de identar, existem várias ferramentas para fazer isso automaticamente, tanto nos editores usados para programar como online. O único propósito de identação em um porgrama em C é tornar a leitura do program mais fácil. Se você usa uma identação inconsistente, isso fica mais difícil, em vez de mais fácil.

Comment: Ouro detalhe, na sua função de gerar strings, a linha `novastr[i + 1] = 0x0;` pode ficar fora do `for`. Não tem nenhum problema a string ser inconsistente enquanto está sendo gerada (a não ser que fosse um programa multi-thread, e houvesse outro código tentando ler a mesma estrutura de dados em paralelo)

Answer (score 2):

Então - o que você precisa ter aí na sua função main é um vetor de ponteiros para strings: 
cada posição no vetor vai na verdade conter o endereço de uma string.

Dessa forma, cada posição no seu vetor aponta para uma string em uma posição diferente da memória. Posteriormente, sua(s) função(ões) de ordenação só vai precisar trocar os valores que estão nessa estrutura de lugar - as strings continuarão onde estão criadas.

Você tanto pode ter um vetor de tamanho máximo fixo, declarado no programa:

```
main () {
   char * dados[100]; 
}
```

como pode usar declarar simplesmente que é um ponteiro para ponteiros,
e alocar memória dinâmicamente:

```
main () {
  char ** dados;
  int tamanho;
  tamanho = ... // obtem o tamanho de alguma fonte externa
  dados = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(char *));

}
```

Nos dois casos, basta fazer um loop chamando sua função geraStringAleatoria, e a cada chamada colocar o ponteiro retornado em uma posição diferente nessa estrutura.

```
main () {
  ...
  for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
    dados[i] = geraStringAleatoria();
  }
  ...
}
```

Sempre é preciso ter em mente que C não tem "strings" - elas funcionam quase como se fossem uma string, mas todas são na verdade uma sequência de bytes em um endereço de memória  - e sempre que passamos ou retornamos uma string como parâmetro, estamos na verdade passando e recuperando esse endereço (ponteiro)